# DotNetHighcharts - How to only use first column of 2d array as Data

Tags: c#, arrays, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I've got a 2d array of objects that I am passing into my seriesSet for creating a column graph, one column is a percentage, which is what I want to see plotted on the graph where the other I only want to show in the tooltip.

Can any of you highcharts geniuses think of a way I can do this? e.g. it looks something like this

```
{ 100, 20 }
{ 100, 20 }
{ 80 , 16 }
{ 80 , 16 }
{ 40 , 8  }
{ 40 , 8  }
{ 20 , 4  }
  ...
```

I know now how to refer to each in the SetToolTip Formatter using 'this.x/this.y/this.point.x' which is progress since I was stuck for a quite a while trying to do that. But now I only want the first set (100, 80, 40, 20) to be used to draw the graph where the second set should only be used for the tooltip.

Coming up on 2 weeks puzzling over this work item so any help is appreciated

edit:
to clarify, the graph draws as I want it to when I pass in a 1D object array consisting of the percentages only, then breaks when I include the second set (the counts)

so I am setting my seriesData like so:

```
List<DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series> seriesSet = new List<DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series>();
seriesSet.Add(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series
{

    Type = chartType,               
    Name = "ExampleArray",
    Data = new DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Data(ExampleArray),
    Color = tarColor,
    PlotOptionsColumn = new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.PlotOptionsColumn
    {
        PointPadding = -0.1
    }, 
});
```

where example array is composed of the list of numbers above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood correctly but if what you want is get a collection of all the first items in this collection and then another one for the second then:

```
// Remove any item that doesn't have at least these two wanted values
items = items.Where(item => item.Count >= 1); 

// Select the sub-collection you need
var percentages = items.Select(item => item[0]);
var tooltips = items.Select(item => item[1]);
```

---

From looking around a bit ([like here](https://github.com/fairmat/DotNet.Highcharts/blob/master/DotNet.Highcharts/DotNet.Highcharts.Samples/Controllers/HoTosController.cs)) it seems you should pass a `Object[]` to the `Data` so replace `ExampleArray` with:

```
items.Select(item => (object)item[0]);
```

---

```
    seriesSet.Add(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Series
    {

        Type = chartType,
        //Name = "Targeted_" + Convert.ToString(tarCount.Count()),                
        Name = "Targeted",
        Data = nnew DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Data((object[])targeted.Cast<object[]>()
                                             .Select(item => (object)item[0])),
        Color = tarColor,
        PlotOptionsColumn = new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.PlotOptionsColumn
        {
            PointPadding = -0.1
        }, 

    });
```

Comment: sort of, but I need to do this in the new series part of the code, so that the secondary set of numbers will be available in the Formatter function for displaying in the tooltip. i'll edit to clarify

Comment: thanks for keeping with me. I see what you mean, but now the problem is that object[*,*] does not contain a definition for 'select'. Is this because the type is of object?

Comment: @bjjrolls - what do you mean a definition for `select`?

Comment: that is the error message i'm getting when i hover over the red underlined select

Comment: I have that included, I can perform .Select on normal lists but not in the way that you have suggested for some reason

Comment: I think it was because I had been trying to use it on a 2d array, i'll edit your answer with what (little) progress i've made to getting the query to run

Comment: Ya I was just about to add the object[,] is a struct and does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` so you should first `cast` it and get and `IEnumerable` on which you can perform those operations

Comment: updated your answer but it wont update until its peer reviewed

Comment: its an array so ToList isn't available. It's erroring on Selecting the decimals out into the object array. I dont know if this will even solve my problem, because really what  I need is to plot the graph using the first column of my 2D array and also have the second column available for creating the tooltips, however I'm just now thinking that filtering the list this way will also exclude the second column... Banging my head off a wall haha

Comment: Thanks a ton. Got that resolved now. Any idea how I can hide one specific label from the Legend? using dotnethighcharts (c#)

Comment: @bjjrolls - I don't have much knowledge about this library... just could manage to help with the error :). If my answer solved your problem I'd appreciate if you mark it as solved :)

Comment: @bjjrolls - but thinking about it, is it a specific one that you know? Maybe you can just replace that specific one with an empty string?

Comment: it is, but I don't know how to access it from the legend formatter at the moment. that sounds like a probable solution though. (also marked question as resolved, my bad)